# Best way to store remote database locally for offline usage (without running mysql server locally)?

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, sqlite, embedded-database

Good morning fellow friends of paleness.

Please help me find a good approach to solve the following problem:

**What am I trying to do?**

I would like to create a c# software that does the following two things:

1. The first part is a database where the user can store contact information. Each set of data consists of around 10 fields, not more than a couple of hundred contacts will be stored, and less than twenty users will have access to the database.
2. Secondly the user shall be able to select a subset of the data by applying filters. He then should be able to send personalized emails to the contacts in these subsets.

**What are the constraints?**

- I would like to store the contact data mainly on a remote server that has mysql capability
- However, when a user is offline, I want him to still be able to access the data, so a way to store the data locally is needed. Selecting subsets and saving email jobs for later execution shall be possible in offline mode
- I do not want the user need to install or start any server locally when he uses the program
- When the user goes online the local and the remote data will be synchronized

**What is the problem?**

The solution I came up with was to store the data locally either in an XML file or embed a database like sqlite in the program. But XML will not be a good choice for the "selecting a subset" feature and both approaches will need conversion to mysql I figured. I know the amount of data is not that big, so maybe either approach is fine. But maybe someone has a better idea altogether?

It would be great to hear your thoughts on how to store the data locally.

Cheers, Essi

Comment: What is wrong with using sqlite locally?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. I am just unexperienced and therefore would like to know the opinion of others...

Comment: For some databases, and some types of operations, Sqlite might be a pain to use because it doesn't manage user permissions, for example. You would need to add a layer handling this if you need it. However, it seems by far the most natural option. If you are shying away because you are unfamiliar with Sqlite, then I suggest becoming familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you for your replies Douglas.